# How do I look up the value of a multi-level pointer inside a process in Python?

Tags: windows, winapi, python-3.x, ctypes

I have a process, and I want to look up a value of an address inside that process but that address is a multi-level pointer and has a few offsets attached to it. How do I do this in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question to document a way of doing this in Python 3.

First you need some way to look up the pid of the process we are working on.

I used the module psutil to do this, but there are other ways to do it too.

```
import psutil

def get_pid(process_name):
    pid = None
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        try:
            if (proc.name() == process_name):
                pid = proc.pid
        except (PermissionError, psutil.AccessDenied):
            pass
    return pid
```

Now we have the pid of the process we want to work on. We'll use that later to get the handle of the process we want to work on.

Now I said it's a multi-level pointer. How that works is that we have an initial address. and a list of offsets. We first of all look up the value of our initial address. We then apply the first offset to that value to get the next address. We look up the value of that address, apply the next offset to that value and get the next address to look up. This can keep going depending on the size of your list of offsets, but say that last look up was the last one and that gives us our final address. When we get the value of that we get the actual value that we are after.

To do this programmatically, we need the pid(For example 4045), the address(For example 0x0163B4D8), the list of offsets(For example [0x37C, 0x3C]) and the size of data(For example an unsigned int is 4 bytes, so that's the size of our data).

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import *

PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = 0x1F0FFF

def read_process_memory(pid, address, offsets, size_of_data):
    # Open the process and get the handle.
    process_handle = windll.kernel32.OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, pid)
    size_of_data = 4 # Size of your data
    data = ""
    read_buff = create_string_buffer(size_of_data)
    count = c_ulong(0)
    current_address = address
    offsets.append(None) # We want a final loop where we actually get the data out, this lets us do that in one go.
    for offset in offsets:
        if not windll.kernel32.ReadProcessMemory(process_handle, current_address, cast(read_buff, LPVOID), size_of_data, byref(count)):
            return -1 # Error, so we're quitting.
        else:
            val = read_buff.value
            result = int.from_bytes(val, byteorder='little')
            # Here that None comes into play.
            if(offset != None):
                current_address = result+offset
            else:
                windll.kernel32.CloseHandle(process_handle)
                return result
```

That's the basic concept, and of course the code could be improved.