# Python Pymem MemoryReadError GetLastError: 299

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, memory-management

Since 2 day i try to read docs of pymem and search an error on forums but all solution i've seen failed

I can't just read the int in the memory address and i don't know if it's a probleme of code or my pc

```
from pymem import *
from pymem.process import module_from_name


pm = pymem.Pymem("***-Win64.exe")

gameModule = module_from_name(pm.process_handle, "***-Win64.exe").lpBaseOfDll

def GetPtrAddr(base, offsets):
    addr = pm.read_int(base) # addr = 9460301, base = 140696812060672
    for i in offsets:
        if i != offsets[-1]:
            addr = pm.read_int(addr + i) # <- here is the error line
    return addr + offsets[-1]

pm.read_int(GetPtrAddr(gameModule + 0x04D934B0, [0x50, 0x30, 0x98, 0xf0, 0x380]))
```

error

```
pymem.exception.MemoryReadError: Could not read memory at: 9460349, length: 4 - GetLastError: 299
```

i tried this too [Reading Memory Address from a process with a Static Address and Offsets in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61845537/reading-memory-address-from-a-process-with-a-static-address-and-offsets-in-pytho) but i have error

```
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <class 'OverflowError'>: int too long to convert
```

but the only value i try to get is from 0 to 12
[image]

I add a try catch in the for loop and here is the error

```
Could not read memory at: 9460349, length: 4 - GetLastError: 299
Could not read memory at: 9460973, length: 4 - GetLastError: 299
Could not read memory at: 9460589, length: 4 - GetLastError: 299
Could not read memory at: 9460301, length: 4 - GetLastError: 299
```

Comment: Could you add the line number of the error? Did your program read the base address successfully? Also, what's the value for the base address here (gameModule + 0x04D934B0)?

Comment: the error is at the line  'addr = pm.read_int(addr + offset)' the value of base is 140696812060672 and addr is 9460301

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fanally found my error thanks to [@Joe_Bao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18699558/joe-bao) for the help

The problem was because my application is in 64bit and i tried to read a int but that's not enough so here the complete code

```
from pymem import *
from pymem.process import *

offsets = [0x50,0x30,0x98,0xF0,0x380]

pm = Pymem('***-Win64.exe')

gameModule = module_from_name(pm.process_handle, '***-Win64.exe').lpBaseOfDll


def GetPointer(base, offsets):
    addr = pm.read_longlong(base+0x04D934B0) # <-- here was the probleme solved
    print(hex(addr))
    for offset in offsets:
        if offset != offsets[-1]:
            try:
                addr = pm.read_longlong(addr + offset)
                print(addr)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
    return addr + offsets[-1]

GetPointer(gameModule, offsets)
```

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why you add the return value from `pm.readint()` with your offset. It seems that `base` is a valid address you can access, while `addr + some offset` isn't.

I read from the [documentation](https://pymem.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) that read_int reads 4 byte from an area of memory in a specified process. Is the return value `addr` the address you want to use?

FYI, I found that the error code is thrown by kernel32, and it means ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY.

Comment: I updated my question with the cheat engine screenshot of the address 
I also tried to just do pm.read(addr) but i have the same error with same code 299

Comment: @Kal-1 What would happen if we directly try to read_int from the memory address "1B5B599 31A0"

Comment: That give me the good result but the problem is this is not the static address if i close and re open the game a new address is generated

Comment: I think i've found the probleme
I don't have the first address 1B5E6419C00 so the rest is fcked up

Comment: May that have something to do with your usage of addr = pm.read_int(base)? I read from the documentation that it only reads 4 bytes (32 bit). I think from the base address "140696812060672" you are probably using 64-bit address. Will read_longlong(address) be what you want?

Comment: pm.read_longlong(base) give me the result "0x300905a4d" but I'm on 64bit application that's true

Comment: lpBaseOfDll is the load address of the module "***-Win64.exe", and I guess maybe you could simply add base with offset, and use pm.read_int(base + offset) to read the int value you want?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243766/discussion-between-kal-1-and-joe-bao).