# Pymem Could not read memory at: , length: 4 - GetLastError: 299

Tags: python, process, cheat-engine, getlasterror

```py
from pymem import *
from pymem.process import *


pm = pymem.Pymem("SHIFT.exe")

gameModule = module_from_name(pm.process_handle , "SHIFT.exe").lpBaseOfDll

def GetptrAddr(base , offsets):

    addr = pm.read_int(base)
    for i in offsets:
        if i != offsets[-1]:
            addr = pm.read_int(addr + i) #problem --> Could not read memory at: 1715211616, length: 4 - GetLastError: 299
    return addr + offsets[-1]

while True:
    pm.write_int(GetptrAddr(gameModule + 0x001F30AC, [0x8E4,0x2C,0x20,0x14,0x10,0x28,0x5C]),11)
```

I use **Cheat engine** and **Pymem** to change the timer in game but it doesn't work.

Cheat Engine7.4 Pointer:
[image: Cheat Engine7.4 Pointer Image]

Pymem Error:
[image: Cheat Engine7.4 Pointer Image]

Comment: please attach the images in the question itself, than having it as hyperlinks

Comment: Your code works fine for me. If you could give us more information it can help.

Comment: Here is your answer is in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71818002/15864765

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change this line

```
gameModule = module_from_name(pm.process_handle , "SHIFT.exe").lpBaseOfDll
```

to this line

```
gameModule = module_from_name(pm.process_handle , "mono.dll").lpBaseOfDll
```

Comment: Why would this answer work?

Comment: I am a beginner, but who i watching him do that , you take it from "mono.dll"+001F30AC